# Php including error while making database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, require, php-include

I have a page header.php which have all the fuctions and db connection pages included in them, i made another page sidebar.php and i included it into another page category.php

So now 
1.header.php - inside header config.php,functions.php
2.category.php - inside this includes header.php and sidebar.php

The problem is the db connection made in the sidebar.php is having error or not connecting when i take the url sidebar.php while includeing the config.php file i get the correct output if not i have nothing

when i include the config in sidebar.php and then include sidebar.php in category.php page i get error

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare db_pconnect() in
>   /var/www/clients/client9/web35/web/beta3/classes/dblib.inc on line 16"

**Code:**
header.php

```
<?php
        require_once '../classes/config.php';
        $cur_file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

        if ($login_required == "YES" && empty($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])) {
            header("location:../login.php");
        }

        require_once '../functions.php';
        ?>
```

category.php

```
<?php require_once("templates/header.php"); ?> 
            <?php include("category_bar.php"); ?> 
               <div class="container">
              <div class="content-second">
              <div class="row">
```

sidebar.php

```
 <?php require_once("templates/header.php"); ?> 
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
```

The page which i needs data code is

```
<?php                                                   
$sql_cat_1 = db_query("Select * from jp_newcat where ncat_parentid='0'");
while($sql_cat_res = db_fetch_object($sql_cat_1)){
?>
<li><a href="category.php?cid=<?php echo $sql_cat_res->ncat_id; ?>"><?php echo $sql_cat_res->ncat_name; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Instead of explaining your code, why not just paste it here? It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're probably including the function _twice_

Comment: hey guys, if i dont add the db file twice i dont get any output,thats also to note please

Answer (score 2):

As per the error, you are including files more than once. You cannot declare the same function twice.
You can use "include_once" instead of using "include".

Comment: You will have to use include_once on all instances of including db_pconnect()

Comment: if i use include for one page and is it neccessary that i should use the same for the same page in another page ?

Comment: Yes. the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. This need to be repeated in all instances including this function db_pconnect()